# Using perspective camera with OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer

Tags: java, libgdx, tiled

I'm trying to get the map to render like this (the bottom image):[image]

I have figured the best way to do this would be a PerspectiveCamera, so I've set up the camera and renderer like this:

```
    // in show
    camera = new PerspectiveCamera(67, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
    camera.position.set(0, 150, 100);
    camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);
    camera.far = 1000;
    camera.update();
    batch = new SpriteBatch();
    
    tiledMap = new TmxMapLoader().load("map.tmx");
    tiledMapRenderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(tiledMap, batch);

    // in render (after glClear)
    camera.update();
    batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);
    tiledMapRenderer.render();
```

This, however does not render the map at all. If I remove the line that sets the projection matrix, the map only renders like this:
[image]

I've seen a similar question here, but that did not explain the solution, one used a parameter that no longer exits. How can I achieve the expected result?

Comment: try `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);` instead of `batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.projection);`

Comment: that did solve it! But it still only renders 2 tiles, any idea what's up with that?

Comment: Hard to say, can you show a screenshot?

Comment: here's the screenshot of the rendered map: https://i.imgur.com/4EpvGQJ.png and here's the map in Tiled: https://imgur.com/a/QYWr4

Comment: At first glance that doesn't look like camera related problem, although I can't really think of anything that could cause it.

Comment: Just wondering if you ever solved this?

Answer (score 1):

I know i'm late to the party, but it's 100% possible.

### The issue

I stepped through gdx internally in the debugger and found that the renderer is only rendering a few tiles because it's failing to calculate the culling frustum correctly, since it does not know anything about the camera.

Typically you'd give feed renderer the viewport by passing it the camera using `r.setView()`, however this only accepts an Orthographic camera.

### The solution

Instead, you must manually specify the viewport region (both position and size) using the sister method with something to the tune of :

`r.setView(cam.combined, cam.position.x - cam.viewportWidth * 0.5f , cam.position.y, cam.viewportWidth, cam.viewportHeight)`

#### two quick side notes for using this camera :

1)`fieldOfView` is your closest replacement for Orthographic's zoom,

however it's of note that the field of view and the renderer's viewport should closely match.

If your renderer's culling area is bigger than your camera's viewing area, it will waste time to render more than can be seen.

I'd suggest looking into scaling the above along with your FOV.

2. A Perspective camera cannot be used to render your Stage UI.

Instead use a Orthographic camera in parallel, or better yet the default Ortho' camera created inside `Stage()`'s constructor.

Multiple cameras will render onto the same screen; show your world first then over-render your HUD.